# takeSample() function in Spark

Tags: scala, random, seeding

I'm trying to use the `takeSample()` function in [Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark) and the parameters are - **data, number of samples to be taken and the seed**. But I don't want to use the seed. I want to have a different answer everytime. I'm not able to figure out how I can do that. I tried using `System.nanoTime` as the seed value but it gave an error since I think the data type didn't match. Is there any other function similar to `takeSample()` that can be used without the seed? Or is there any other implementation I can use with `takeSample()` so that I get a different output every time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`System.nanoTime` is of type `long`, the seed expected by `takeSample` is of type `Int`. Hence, `takeSample(..., System.nanoTime.toInt)` should work.

Comment: In scala `.toInt` should be prefered over `.intValue`

Answer (score 1):

`System.nanoTime` returns Long, whereas takeSample expects an Int.
You can feed `scala.util.Random.nextInt` as a seed value to the takeSample function.

Answer (score 1):

As of Spark version 1.0.0, the `seed` parameter is optional.  See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1438.